# Entity framework and linq to entity performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I've been investigating using Microsoft's entity framework for a project at work.  I created a simple little data layer solution which has an IDataService interface so I could write a standard ADO.Net implementation and an Entity Framework version using Linq-to-Entity.

I've created two tests which request exactly the same data, but use the different implementations.  The queries are simple, they retrieve data from a table, and using hierarchical information generate a DTO with the data in a hierarchy.

The data in the database is along the lines of

```
------------------------
ID  | Description
----|-------------------
1   | Item 1
2   | Item 2
3   | Item 3
4   | Item 4
5   | Item 5

----------------
Parent | Child  
-------|--------
1      | 2
1      | 3
3      | 4
1      | 5

Desired Output
--------------
Item 1
|-Item 2
|-Item 3
| |-Item 4 
|-Item 5
```

And so the queries currently take the form of:

```
from a in tableA
join b in tableB on b.Parent equals a.ID
where b.Parent == root.ID
select new DTO.Entry {
  Id = a.ID
  ...
}
```

The method containing this query is run recursively until there are no more child elements left to process.

Using Linq-to-entity the test takes about 320ms to complete, using ADO.Net the tests takes about 8ms!

Is this just something I have to live with/consider or should the performance be about on par?  Also, as the underlying data structure has no referential integrity (I know!), so I am compensating for this in my ADO.Net stuff, but I can't with Entities, is this likely to have an impact?

At the moment it seems that if you want performance then you should stick with ADO.Net

Comment: Can you add more information, as in what was the query and what is the datastore?

Comment: and what version of entity framework are you using? BTW an interesting link considering performance measurement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/04/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-1.aspx

Comment: It's EF 4.5 (I'm using VS2012 so I'm guessing that's right?).  Thanks for the link, I'm scanning over it now

Comment: @daz-fuller: the EF creates objects out of the query results. do you by chance do the same in the ado.net test? also, do you perform like 10 tests and take the average value (to compensate the warm-up of the EF)?

Comment: The ADO.Net instance is executing the query, iterating over the reader and creating the object from each record.  I've not accounted for warm up time, I'll re-run the tests and see how that affects it.

Comment: Okay, I re-did the tests to run the same set of queries 100 times for both the ADO.Net and Entity tests.  Results are 3sec for Entity and 170ms for ADO.Net

Comment: Looking at the output from the SQL profiler there's not much in the performance, other than because of the lack of foreign keys I'm having to run twice as many queries using EF.

Comment: well I think you well never reach the same speed with EF as in classic ado.net. In my humble opinion the strength of EF is not speed but saving development time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask a customer: do you want more performance or less bugs?

Of course plain ADO.Net performs better than a data layer that also uses ADO.Net but before and after that does a lot more. Moreover, you chose an area where EF is not a good competitor when it comes to efficiency: recursive queries. But generally, when it comes to writing correct, stable code that performs *acceptably*, EF (or any seasoned OR mapper) rises head and shoulders above ADO.Net. It is hand-written SQL and data driven programming vs. linq and object oriented programming.

Nevertheless, you right when you say

> At the moment it seems that if you want performance then you should stick with ADO.Net

Sure, for performance-critical operations OR mappers tend to have too much internal overhead to fit the bill. And to return to recursive queries: nothing beats recursive queries with CTE's in the database.